# How to identify temp setting on a CH-152-35 thermostat

Tags: identification

Pictured is a CH-152-35 thermostat. It is similar but not identical to the one described at http://www.wako-clinac.co.jp/product_en/ch-152-35_en/index.html

I don't have a way to heat this thermostat in a controlled fashion until the switch opens- So I cannot determine its temperature setting by experimentation.

There is more information than just the part number printed on the side of it. I am thinking that *perhaps* the "195" on the second row of text is the temperature rating - but I cannot find anything via Google that takes my idea from a guess to a fact.

Can someone please tell me if that "195" number is indeed the temperature setting for the thermostat and if the "4131" at bottom is useful information?

As a further help, maybe explain if this is standard marking technique for this type of component and where a reference for these markings might live?

[image: CH-152-35]

Comment: `I don't have a way to heat this thermostat in a controlled fashion` ... do you have access to a kitchen with an oven?

Comment: LOL, yes. Yes, I do. And if I put electronics inside of it with leads coming out to a meter or a lamp, I will pay very very dearly for doing so. Not everything is available for experimental use...

Comment: Just say that you're calibrating the oven so that it behaves better ... Practice an air of confidence while doing so ...

Comment: Come for an electronics answer... get relationship management advice! LOL! Any input regarding the markings in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cantherm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/R53_APRIL_2015.pdf) is an example datasheet for similar thermostats.

You will note that there is not only just a nominal temperature, but the thermostat may be open or close at temperatures beyond the switching region, there is a (usually large) hysteresis which may be above, below or above and below the nominal temperature, and a tolerance. Of course there are electrical and life ratings as well, and usually safety agency approval numbers.

[image]

Chances are the second number is the temperature, and the bottom number is a date code, but that's just a (reasonable) guess.

Comment: Also verified temperature range of this thermostat by accidentally finding the schematics for the printer this came out of.